# tokenizing: how to not tokenize punctuation like `^* in python for NLP

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, nltk, tokenize

**I want to tokenize string punctuation except `*^**

I've tried but the result, all types of punctuation are separated, while for some punctuation I don't want to separate

when i use:

```
text = "hai*ini^ema`il saya lunar!?"
tokenizer = TweetTokenizer()
nltk_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
nltk_tokens
```

i get:

```
['hai', '*', 'ini', '^', 'ema', '`', 'il', 'saya', 'lunar', '!', '?']
```

what i want is:

```
['hai*ini^ema`il', 'saya', 'lunar', '!', '?']
```

I want to tokenize but not tokenize *^`

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: python for cleaning data in NLP case

Comment: sorry, that wasn't clear: What language is hai*ini^ema`il saya lunar!?

Comment: ahh the language is bahasa Indonesia sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def phrasalize(tokens):
    s = " ".join(tokens)
    match = re.match("((\w*\s[\*\^\`]\s\w*)+)", s)
    while match:
        s = s.replace(match.group(1), match.group(1).replace(' ', ''))
        match = re.match("((\w*\s[\*\^\`]\s\w*)+)", s)
    return s

tokens = ['hai', '*', 'ini', '^', 'ema', '`', 'il', 'saya', 'lunar', '!', '?']
phrasalize(tokens)
```

[out]:

```
'hai*ini^ema`il saya lunar ! ?'
```